# MacTex 2023, PDFLatex is (apparently) an alias to pdfTeX and I got the following error:

Tags: mactex, texlive-2023

Everything was running ok with my LaTeX documents, but after installing MacTex 2023, PDFLatex is (apparently) an alias to pdfTeX and I got the following error:

```
running: /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin/pdftex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode primerMathQC.tex 
pdflatex> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdftex)
pdflatex>  restricted \write18 enabled.
pdflatex> entering extended mode
pdflatex> (./primerMathQC.tex
pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
pdflatex> l.1 \documentclass
pdflatex>                   [english,spanish,letter]{tufte-handout}
```

I appreciate any orientation you can give me. Thanks.

Comment: `preloaded format=pdftex` shows you ran `pdftex` not`pdflatex`

Comment: you are not saying how you call pdflatex

Comment: pdflatex has been a symbolic link to pdftex in texlive since last century, but they behave differently

Comment: Well, I am using Eclipse with TexElipse... but I don't know why in the new installation pdflatex is pointing to pdftex.

Comment: Thanks David Carlisle, but then, if there is a symbolic link from pdlatex to pdftex, where can I find the real pdflatex? Thanks.

Comment: that is the real pdflatex, there is not a separate program the binary checks the name under which it was called and acts accordingly. You show `running: /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin/pdftex`so you called it as pdftex so it loads plain tex and reports `(preloaded format=pdftex)`  if you call it as `pdflatex` it would preload `pdflatex` format

Comment: Thanks David... but is not clear for me how to change the (preloaded format=pdftex) to (preloaded format=pdflatex)... any hints?  thanks.

Comment: maybe you're using some editor? In that case check that you're configuring the file paths etc. correctly. (show us what's your current configuration otherwise we have no idea.)

Comment: hard to say David... I am using TeXlipse in Eclipse IDE... and apparently TeXlipse is not active any more.
There is no way to know what is doing TeXlipse under the hood.

Comment: Is the editor actually set up got use the TeX Live 2023 installation? The binaries should be found in `/Library/TeX/texbin` in a standard MacTeX installation.

Comment: you are executing  `pdftex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode primerMathQC.tex` when you want `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode primerMathQC.tex` so you just need to type the correct command, either in the terminal or in the editor setup for whatever menu option you used.